# A little help in confirming an interpretation on an output

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, residuals, leverage

How can we interpret the results in the graph below?

Does the R command lm() uses Heteroskedasticity-consistent covariance matrices(HCCM) estimators, or HAC estimators for the inference tests?

The residuals vs fitted plot seems to indicate that I'm dealing with homoskedastic case. The scale-location seems to also tell me the same thing.
The mean of the residuals also appears to be zero, so no problem with the OLS estimate for the intercept, right?

For the normal Q-Q I could find info on the net, and it seems that my residuals are following a normal distribution (heavy-tailed?). Can I also infer that they are independent? Since it follows a normal, then the t-stat. given by R are valid not only asymptotically, but also exactly for this sample size, right?

Should I take care of outliers? From some info on an answer on CV, it seems that my Residual vs Leverage is good, since it's close to the axis when far in the right, so it's in between the contour of ellipses with  value 0.5. So there doesn't seem to exist a high leverage-high residual observations. True?

[image]

Comment: A case can be made that the set of points in the top left plot are not really outliers and might have a story to tell, since there are many points clustered in that area. I don't know what the regression model is, but those "outliers" might be because you are failing to capture that information.

Comment: @Greenparker Thanks for your comment. yes, I think you're right. By the way, do you agree with my analysis on the plot data? I would like to know if I'm wrong in any aspect.

Comment: By construction, the mean of the residuals is always going to be 0, and so that gives you no information. The QQ plot interpretation is mostly right, although it is not symmetrically heavy tailed since the lower tails seem to be heavier. You cannot check the independence assumption from any of these plots. That is almost uncheckable in most cases. Sometime, the residuals plot might tell you a seasonal style pattern indicating dependent data, but that rarely happens.